# how to build notification pop up system from cloud to local computer

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, push-notification

I'm trying to build a notification system that would be triggered initially from an api call made on the cloud, and should trigger a notification on one of my agents' pc (assuming running windows 10)

I'd like to do that in python as this is my knowledge

How should I structure this ?

The hardest part I can't figure out and couldn't find anything online is how to link the "local" pc to the "server"/cloud system (i'm using aws if that is useful) which would store the notification and dispatch them for each one of my agent.

My ultimate goal is to use a phone solution like aircall and to show the contact name of the caller through a notification popup in windows (aircall does offer that natively but can't access my contact datrabase so i'm trying to override the same function of displaying the caller name)

any help or suggesiton appreciated

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to build a simple ElectronJS frontend app that runs on your agents' computer AND a Python web server that listens to Aircall's Webhook events.

The **web server** would listen to `call.ringing_on_agent` Webhook events sent from Aircall and send a WebSocket push event (using [Pusher](https://pusher.com/) for example) to your ElectronJS app.

The **[ElectronJS](https://www.electronjs.org/) app** installed by your agents would listen to WebSockets from your Python web server and would trigger a native Windows notification with the information you want ([check the doc here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/notifications)).